# pd.json_normalize() does not go through all the levels of the Json data

Tags: json, pandas

This is my first ever question here :)

I want to flatten a Json file with multiple levels using pandas.json_normalize (or anything else that works!) in order to parse through all the levels. I tried many ways, such as adding record_path, max_levels but nothing works.
the result I obtain is only 2 columns: one with time and the other is a string with all the rest of data.
this is part of the data as it shows in the file:

[When visualizing the following data you get this, belwo is the raw data from the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvLoR.png)

{"data":[{"time":"1630914886924","Responses":[{  "lines": [    {      "lineId": "1",      "vehiclePositions": [        {          "directionId": "8161",          "distanceFromPoint": 1,          "pointId": "8012"        },        {          "directionId": "8162",          "distanceFromPoint": 0,          "pointId": "8142"        },        {          "directionId": "8162",          "distanceFromPoint": 0,          "pointId": "8282"        },        {          "directionId": "8731",          "distanceFromPoint": 0,          "pointId": "8111"        },        {          "directionId": "8162",          "distanceFromPoint": 1,          "pointId": "8062"        },        {          "directionId": "8731",          "distanceFromPoint": 0,          "pointId": "8281"        },        {          "directionId": "8161",          "distanceFromPoint": 1,          "pointId": "8102"        },

and this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
file = open("vp1.json")
json_obj = json.load(file)
df = pd.json_normalize(json_obj['data'])
```

This is the output when I do df.head():

```
time    Responses
0   1630914886924   [{'lines': [{'lineId': '1', 'vehiclePositions'...
1   1630914917746   [{'lines': [{'lineId': '1', 'vehiclePositions'...
2   1630914948365   [{'lines': [{'lineId': '1', 'vehiclePositions'...
3   1630914978881   [{'lines': [{'lineId': '1', 'vehiclePositions'...
4   1630915011138   [{'lines': [{'lineId': '1', 'vehiclePositions'...
```